# Preventing code duplication when initializing with and without arguments

Tags: c++, c++03

I have a factory that creates objects of type `T` through a `Create` method. `T` either does or does not have a constructor that take parameters. I want to be able to pass parameters optionally. This is what I have:

```
template<typename U>
T* Create(U const& arg) {
  if (nodes_.empty()) {
    return new T(arg);
  }

  void* n = nodes_.front();
  nodes_.pop_front();
  return new (n) T(arg);
}

T* Create() {
  if (nodes_.empty()) {
    return new T();
  }

  void* n = nodes_.front();
  nodes_.pop_front();
  return new (n) T();
}
```

I'm abhor the code duplication I'm incurring. If this was C++11 I would simply use a parameter pack and forward them to the constructor. But unfortunately I cannot use that standard. Is there any way I can merge this into a single interface?

Also, the object that I'm working with is `const` so I can't just default-construct and assign data members later.

Comment: Is it possible to define a default value in the parameter for if it was not set? Ex: `T* Create(U const& arg = null) {...}` I'm not at my computer at the moment to test this. If you could do this then you will be able to only define the Create function once.

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling `front` and `pop_back`? @JohnOdom: Wouldn't that cause nearly as much duplication to avoid calling `T(null)`?

Comment: @Guvante I have a `std::deque` of nodes. When the user requests memory, if the node list is empty, I give them a constructed one, otherwise I take from the deque, initialize them, remove them from the deque and return them.

Comment: @templateboy: His point is that you're popping a different node than you're using.  This code always uses the first node over and over and just removes the last node without using it.

Comment: @MooingDuck Meant for that to be `pop_front`. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use a blurb akin to this:

```
struct do_default_construct {};
template<class T, class U> 
T* construct(T* p, U const& v) {return new (p)T(v);}
template<class T> 
T* construct(T* p, do_default_construct const& v) {return new (p)T();}
```

And then your specialization can simply call the generic version:

```
template<typename U>
T* Create(U const& arg) {
  if (nodes_.empty()) {
    return new T(arg);
  }

  void* n = nodes_.front();
  nodes_.pop_front(); //irrelevant bugfix here
  return construct<T>(n, arg); //use overloaded function
}
T* Create() {
    const do_default_construct t; 
    return Create(t); //call generic version
}
```